# Instantiating Generic Type in class: V extends List

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, extends

I'm trying to develop a class that works with objects who extend java.util.List, for example, ArrayList. Below is an example of what I think should compile (assuming the necessary import statements):

```
public class MyClass<V extends List> {

    V myList = new ArrayList();

    MyClass<ArrayList> myinstance = new MyClass<>();
}
```

While the "myinstace" is no problem, the compiler fails when attempting to instantiate "myList.":

> MyClass.java:[17,16] incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList cannot be
>   converted to V

As I understand generics, declaring:

```
<V extends List>
```

implies that whatever type "V" is, it must be a subclass of "List." Thus, why cannot I instantiate as above, and is there any correct way to instantiate an object of type "V" within the class?

Furthermore, how might one return an object of type "V" within a method in the class?

```
public V getSomeData(){
    // How do we create our object of type "V"?
}
```

**Background**

I have an interface, PatternElement:

```
public interface PatternElement<D,W> {

    /**
     * The data that this element contains or signifies.
     * @return 
     */
    public D getData();

    /**
     * The width of this pattern element within a pattern.
     * @return 
     */
    public W getWidth();

}
```

I'm trying to develop a subclass, PolyPatternElement, which can contain many "data" and "width" items within itself. I thought the following code would accomplish this...

```
public class PolyPatternElement<V extends List, W extends List> implements PatternElement<V,W>{


    @Override
    public V getData() {
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public W getWidth() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, "getData" doesn't compile. Thus, I narrowed down the problem and asked the original question. After the feedback, I think the better PolyPatternElement definition is:

```
public class PolyPatternElement<V,W> implements PatternElement<List,List>{


    @Override
    public List getData() {
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public List getWidth() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

This allows declaring a PolyPatternElement object whose types are any implementation of List which was my intention.

Comment: Why´d you use a generic `V` if it will be an `ArrayList` in every case?

Comment: What if someone will pick for `V` `LinkedList` like `MyClass<LinkedList>`? Would `V myList = new ArrayList();` make sense then? `V` doesn't represent (can't hold) *any* list, but *some specific* but yet *unknown* list.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point @Pshemo. What if I want to return an object of this type, "V." within my class...I added in that.

Comment: @Vance-Turner the proper way would be a constructor as `MyClass(V myList)` and in there you´d set `myList`.

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are facing. If your `myList` is of type `V` and it holds some instance (lets say you passed it via constructor `MyClass(V myList)`, or method `setList(V myList)`) then you can create method which will also return this list like `V getList(){ return myList;}`. So there is no problem with *returning* it. What you can't do is create `V` instance with `new` operator or since we don't know what `V` will represent (not to mention that generics are erased at runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (untested):

```
public class PolyPatternElement<V, W> implements PatternElement<List<V>, List<W>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

> ... implies that whatever type "V" is, it must be a subclass of "List."

Within a generic class you cannot simply instantiate an object of the generic parameters class.

```
public class MyClass<V extends List> {

    V myList = new ArrayList();  // <-- What if 'V' is 'LinkedList'?

}
```

You either have to provide the class or an object with the constructor:

```
public class MyClass<V extends List> {

    private final V myList;

    public MyClass(V theList) {
        this.myList = theList;
    }

    public MyClass(Class<V> listType) {
        this.myList = listType.newInstance(); // works only if 'listType' has default constructor.
    }

}
```